# Limit the browser windows height can not less than 200 px using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, screen

I would like the user can not drag the surrounding line of browser and resize the browser when the window size is less than 200 px;

```
//if ($(window).height > 200){
$(window).resize(function() {
after_resize(function(){
    Book.zoom_auto();
    Book.book_position();
    Book.dragdrop_init();
    calculate_zoom_factor();

    if ($(".viewportBinder").length){                   
    $("#view").css('height',$(window).height());
    $("#view").css('width',$(window).width());  
    content = element.viewport('update');
    }

}, 300);
});
//}
```

This if statement can order not to do anything if the size is less than 200px , however, is it possible to not allow the user drag the screen? (The current situation is user can still drag to the height less than 200px, but it will do nothing) Thanks

Comment: AFAIK No. Your web page has nothing to do with the browser it self.

Comment: Thanks for reply . not really , i visit some website can fixed the border of the browser window?

Comment: but the fixed border is width only, so I wonder if height can do the same thing

Comment: @Jed Watson - There could be one way to stop user from shrinking screen size less than 200 px, You can fire alert() every time the user tries to shrink screen less than 200px, hence user will get alert every time. Might help You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to control whether the user can resize or move the browser window from Javascript.

..imagine the problems you'd have with popups and spam ads if you could (!)

Answer (score 1):

If the browser lets you do [`window.resizeTo(w,h)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo), than you can set it. BUT modern day browsers normally disable that method by default.

Answer (score -3):

It's seems that medium is doing it:
https://medium.com